# how to check empty value in javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript

```
var value1 = (something)
var value2 = (something)
```

I want to put these 2 values in an if statement. If value1 exists and value2 doesn't exist, set input = value2;

here's what I did but It's not correct and i cant figure out why.

```
if(value1 == true && value2 !== true)
   input=value2;
```

what am I doing wrong??? any easier way to do this?

Comment: Why would you set `input = value2` if value2 doesn't exist, that's a reference error ?

Comment: What is wrong with your proposed solution?

Comment: @adeneo If he does ``value2 = (something)``, ``value2`` does exist or did I miss something here?

Comment: Maybe providing a more concrete example would help...

Comment: @ThreeFx - I was actually reading the question, *"value2 doesn't exist, set input = value2"*, but I could be wrong ?

Comment: @adeneo I would say it is unclear what he is asking for as his examples show ``value2 = (something)`` but his text says *"value2 doesn't exist, set input = value2"*

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Javscript's equality testing is a little bit strange. Doing `value1 == true` will check if `value1` equals the string `true`. Doing `===` on them will not work because `===` requires its arguments to have the same type. The simplest solution for your problem is:

```
if (value1 && !value2)
{
    value2 = input;
}
```

Comment: how is this different than what I have?

Comment: @lolwuwu The difference between ``if (value1)`` and ``if (value1 == true)`` lies in what is being checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof var_name == 'undefined') {
    // ...
}
```